# Como enviar imagens de WinForm para um serviço WebAPI c# dos dois lados

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tenho duas aplicações, um WinForm rodando local e um WebApi hospedado remoto.

Já envio dados para o servido a partir do WinForm, o código é assim:

```html
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string DATA = json_serializer.Serialize(MEUOBJETO);


HttpWebRequest request;

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

request.Method = "POST";
request.Proxy = null;
request.ContentType = "application/json";

byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DATA);
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
newStream.Close();

request.GetResponse();
```

Gostaria saber como eu posso colocar uma imagem nesse `MEUOBJETO` para serializar tudo junto e enviar.

Daria para fazer isso?
Como ficaria o lado do Servidor?

Meu servidor recebe os dados da seguinte forma:

```html
[Route("MINHA ROTA")]
public HttpResponseMessage POST( [FromBody]MEUOBJETO obj)
{

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar uma propriedade do tipo `String` no `MEUOBJETO` e carregar a imagem serializada como string Base64:

```
string imagemBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(umaImagem); // umaImagem é um byte[]
MEUOBJETO.ImagemBase64 = imagemBase64;
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string DATA = json_serializer.Serialize(MEUOBJETO);
```

Depois, do lado do Web.API é só converter de volta para `byte[]`:

```
[Route("MINHA ROTA")]
public HttpResponseMessage POST([FromBody]MEUOBJETO obj)
{
    byte[] imagem = Convert.FromBase64String(obj.ImagemBase64);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
}
```